# Исправить ошибку mypy

Tags: python, типизация, mypy

Проверяю свой код анализатором `mypy`. Возникли следующие ошибки:

1. Имеется объект `names: List[str]`, на выражение `len(names)` выдается ошибка

   `Argument 1 to "len" has incompatible type "Optional[List[str]]"; expected "Sized"`

   При индексации `names[i]` выдается следующая ошибка:

   `Value of type "Optional[List[str]]" is not indexable`
2. Имеется объект `matrix: List[List[int]]`, аналогично при индексации `matrix[i][j]`

   `Value of type "Optional[List[List[int]]]" is not indexable`
3. Имеется объект

   ```
    def func() -> Dict[str, List[str]]
        g = {"1": ["2"],
            "2": ["3"]}
        return g
   ```

   описанный как `Dict[str, List[str]]`, вылетает ошибка:

   `Incompatible return value type (got "Dict[str, object]", expected "Dict[str, List[str]]")`
   Неясно, почему получился такой тип. Если изменить его на `Dict[str, object]`, дальше по коду появляются ошибки.
4. При обращении к объекту из п. 3:

   ```
    d: DefaultDict[str, List[str]] = defaultdict(list)
    for obj in g:
        d[obj].extend(g.get(obj))
   ```

   Вылетает следующая ошибка:

   `Argument 1 to "extend" of "list" has incompatible type "Optional[List[str]]"; expected "Iterable[str]"`

Я новичок в `python` и не очень понимаю принципы корректной работы с `mypy` - как мне грамотно писать аннотации к типам, чтобы не получать таких ошибок?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### 1 и 2:

`Optional` говорит о том, что у вас значение может быть не только заданного через аннотацию типа, но и `None` - например, если `None` задано в значении параметра по-умолчанию для функции. Дальше вы не проверяя значение на `None` пытаетесь с этими значениями работать как со списками. Нужно добавить проверку на `None`, тогда ошибок не будет.

Пример:

```
# Неправильно:
def test(names: List[str]=None, matrix: List[List[int]]=None):
    print(names[0])  # Ошибка: Value of type "Optional[List[str]]" is not indexable
    print(len(names))  # Ошибка: Argument 1 to "len" has incompatible type "Optional[List[str]]"; expected "Sized"
    print(matrix[0][0])  # Ошибка: Value of type "Optional[List[List[int]]]" is not indexable


# Правильно:
def test(names: List[str]=None, matrix: List[List[int]]=None):
    if names is not None:
        print(names[0])
        print(len(names))

    if matrix is not None:
        print(matrix[0][0])
```

#### 3:

Вы забыли двоеточие в конце строки `def`, а так mypy ошибок не выдает:

```
def func() -> Dict[str, List[str]]:  # <-- добавил двоеточие
    g = {"1": ["2"],
        "2": ["3"]}
    return g
```

#### 4:

Метод `get` словаря может возвращать `None`, если ключа в словаре нет (т.е. у него тип возвращаемого значения `Optional[тип значения из словаря]`). Т.к. ключи берутся из этого же словаря, то ситуация, когда вернется `None`, фактически невозможна, но mypy не настолько умный, чтобы это понимать. Нужно просто заменить получение значения через `get` на получение через квадратные скобки, тогда ошибка пропадет:

```
g = func()
d: DefaultDict[str, List[str]] = defaultdict(list)
for obj in g:
    d[obj].extend(g[obj])  # было g.get(obj), стало g[obj]
```

Comment: Если в пункте 3 сделать `g = {"1":["2", "3"], "2": "3", "4": []}` все ломается и получается `Dict[str, object]` вместо `Dict[str, List[str]]`, неясно почему :(

Comment: Потому что у ключа "2" значение "3" - а это явно не список. Чтобы было `Dict[str, List[str]]`, должно быть `g = {"1":["2", "3"], "2": ["3"], "4": []}`

Comment: ошибочка вышла, там стояли изначально квадратные скобки, но почему-то `mypy` все равно ругается

Comment: я подозреваю, что проблема в том, что используются такие ключи как `"4": []`

Comment: Да, похоже на то. Но если напрямую `return {"1":["2", "3"], "2": ["3"], "4": []}` сделать или добавить аннотацию к инициализации переменной (`g : Dict[str, List[str]] = {"1":["2", "3"], "2": ["3"], "4": []}`), то ошибка пропадет. Видимо предполагается, что если явно не указана аннотация, то пустой список может содержать любой объект.

Comment: @Angelika, если ответ вам помог, вы можете отметить его принятым (поставить галку слева от ответа)